# How to get date from Google Sheet to date type HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom HTML form bounded with Google sheet.
I can take any text from Google and set it as value for text type HTML elements like this

```js
var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('<?= my_text ?>');
template.my_text = 'Hello World!';
template.evaluate();
```

But it does not work with dates.

```js
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('<input type="date" value="<?= my_date ?>'>");
    template.my_date = '10-05-2020';
    template.evaluate();
```

How can I fix it well?
How can I get date from cell and set it as value at the date type input element in HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.getDisplayValue()`

```js
var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('<?= my_text ?>');
template.my_text = SpreadsheetApp
                    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
                    .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
                    .getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
template.evaluate();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to get Date from cell and set as Date to element like `<input type="date"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the date in the format ***YYYY-MM-DD***, otherwise, it will not work. This is an example that you can follow:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?= my_text ?></h1>
    <input type="date" value="<?= my_date ?>">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Apps Script

```
function doGet() {
  var template =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  template.my_text = "Hello World!";
  template.my_date = "2020-04-29"
  return template.evaluate();
}
```

***P.S:*** I used [these docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to help you.